# How to select time on my chart js graph on Django?

Tags: django, charts

I'm trying to do a selection on what only will be displayed on my chart, but I don't know what it's called hehe. please help

my views.py look like this.

```
class ResView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Rainfall
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'res'
    paginate_by = 8
    queryset = Rainfall.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["qs"] = Rainfall.objects.all()
        return context
```

my chart look like this.

```
<script>

            (function () {

  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [{% for i in qs %}'{{i.timestamp}}',{% endfor %}],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Rainfall Graph',
        data: [{% for i in qs %}'{{i.amount}}',{% endfor %}],
        lineTension: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: '#c9c5c5',
        borderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,

      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: false
          }
        }]
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  })
}());
```

Now I want to select what to display on my chart. something like a dropdown like this. That I have an option.

```
<select>
<option value="hour">Hour</option>
<option value="day">Day</option>
<option value="month">Month</option>
</select>
```